# Laravel : route not hitting controller

Tags: debugging, laravel-4

> Route::any('mobileLogin', ['as' => 'mobileLogin', 'uses' =>
>   'App\Controllers\LoginController@mobileLogin']);

For some reason my perfectly working route has stopped working and a "**whoops**" error is being shown using  **app/views/error-page.blade.php**

Here is the controller function:

```
public function mobileLogin()
{
    try
    {
        Log::info('----------------');
        Log::info('Inside mobileLogin');
    }
    catch (\Exception $e)
    {
        Log::info('*********** ERROR**************');
        Log::info('Message: ' . $e->getMessage());
        Log::info('Trace String : ' . $e->getTraceAsString());
        Log::info("*********** END of ERROR *************");
    }
}
```

The **/app/storage/logs/laravel.log** don't show any error, hence trying to find what exactly went wrong.

In my **config/app.php** debug is set to true as well.

I've put log messages in my controller function as well, but it's failing before it even reaches there !

How does one debug this ?
If Laravel framework isn't routing to the controller itself, then where can I dig for the issue ?

Comment: It's working perfectly on another virtual host, but stopped working on another one in production - on the same host.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue - it was an error in one of the php files itself.
I expected for a syntax error an error would show in the laravel.log, but no !

There is another error.log at the base of the app, which luckily had it !